# Tor relay server behind proxy

Tags: proxy, socks

I'm a newbie in the Tor world. I was just thinking of running a relay server... The fact is that I know some sites like Netflix, Disney and others just block all the relays IPs that are posted on the TOR Relays List. So I thought I could use a proxy to camouflage the relay server.

I spent some time thinking about this, I realized that I have to use a SOCKS proxy that Clients or Guard nodes see in the Tor list as public IP, and the request is transferred to the actual relay server so it can connect to the exit node.

Can someone help me? I'm running the relay (now is a bridge for test while I don't have an IP SOCKS) on Ubuntu GNU/Linux

Comment: Why won't you just keep running a bridge instead? The Tor network can really use some more bridges.

Comment: I want the server to be available as a relay, not a bridge, maybe even with a bridge it could be IP banned from some sites, maybe those sites request bridges just to ban those, who knows? Using an alternative IP helps me not being blacklisted

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your socks proxy is allowing you to open a port to listen, then it's fine. Otherwise it's not a vital case. If you need further help don't hesitate to contact me! I'll be glad to help!

Comment: I just figured out that I need a Reverse proxy so clients just connect to the proxy and it forwards the traffic to my relay. I don't want to use another machine for hosting only the reverse proxy service, can I use a service to rent? What should I use?

Comment: You can use a digital ocean droplet, and you don't need a reverse proxy: socks protocol has already got it out of the box and it's just a server side tuning

Comment: You mean the VPS? Cause I didn't ask for a VPS service, I would just use a Reverse Proxy Service for forwarding the traffic from the Proxy Server to the Relay Tor Server on my current machine

Comment: Well, if you have such a service with a static IP address and it will be easier for you - okay, go ahead! But actually a proper fully functional socks5 service is ok for you to achieve your goals

Answer (score 0):

"block all the relays IPs that are posted on the TOR Relays List."

That is where you are mistaken. That is not what happens, there is provided by Tor Project itself Onionoo API, that allows anyone to query an IP address and ask whether it is an exit node or relay, so that makes Tor useless for editing wikipedia, e.g. or really using any CDN, Google, Cloudflare.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TorBlock

https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-TorBlock/commit/b7be2169909d1f809c92f3f5dfff79b28af6e9c4